# A problem on infinite sum relating to 'size' of complement of a compact set with empty interior on $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Suppose we have a series of open intervals on $[0,1]$. Let's call their union A. There are a countably infinite number of them. Now, suppose that for any point x in $[0,1]$, there is a sequence of intervals $(a_i,b_i)$ such that either $b_i$ tends to $x$, or $a_i$ does, or both do.

My question is then, does $\sum |b_i - a_i|$ necessarily converge to 1? The sum is easily verified to exist and is absolutely summable (as the finite sums are bounded above by 1). I have tried to prove it but am very stuck. It seems intuitive because viewed as a set, its complement has empty interior and is closed.

Edit: the open intervals should be pairwise disjoint. E.g., if we took the complement of the cantor set and wrote it as the union of a countably infinite number of disjoint open intervals.

Edit 2: I meant to say that every point in $[0,1]$ is either in one of the open intervals, or a limit of the endpoints. It would have been simpler to say that the closure of the sets is $[0,1]$. or a sorry I should have made this clear the first time.

Edit 3: I think(?) I have a potential counterexample now that I have made the statement clearer! We construct our series of open intervals as follows. We create an enumeration of all the rationals. We take the first rational, and create an open interval of width of length $1/4$ around it. Inductively, when we get to the kth rational, if it is one of the preceding open intervals, then we do not create a new open interval. If it is not in an existing open interval, then we create a new open interval of length at most $\frac{1}{4^k}$ in width, and smaller if need be to avoid intersecting with any of the existing open intervals.
Then this construction has total length bounded above by $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16}+ \frac{1}{64}...$  but it is equally clear that its closure contains all of $[0,1]$. (This seems somewhat paradoxical, as its complement, which has empty interior and is compact, has non zero measure!!)

Comment: You don't say it, but do you mean to assume the open intervals are pairwise disjoint?

Comment: Let $I$ be the collection of open intervals that contain rational endpoints strictly between $0$ and $1$. Then for any $x \in [0,1]$, there exists intervals such that their endpoints converge to $x$. However, the sum of the length of those intervals will diverge since $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ is contained in $I$.

Comment: yep pairwise disjoint

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain I should have clarified, the intervals should be pairwise disjoint

Comment: The intervals cannot be pairwise-disjoint. If $a_i<b_j$ and $x\in (a_i,b_i)$ then $x$ cannot be the limit of some end-points of some set of $(a_j,b_j)$ unless some $a_j$ or $b_j$ is in $(a_i,b_i),$ (with $a_j<b_j$), which implies that $(a_i,b_i)\ne (a_j,b_j)$ and $(a_i,b_i)\cap (a_j,b_j)\ne \emptyset.$

Comment: ahh sorry I was unclear again. I mean to say that every point is either in one of the intervals or is a limit point of the endpoints. In hindsight I should have just said that the closure of the intervals was $[0,1]$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet sorry to bother you. I have made the question clearer and I think in doing so have seen a way to answer it., by constructing a set of disjoint open intervals containing all the rationals with measure less than 1. This bothers me a little, as intuitively it seemed that a compact set with empty interior should have measure 0, but I did a quick surf of the web and it seems this is a common kind of construction

Comment: If the intervals are non-empty and pairwise-disjoint then it is not possible for a point in the middle of one of the intervals to be a limit of the set of end-points of the intervals. However the union of all the points in all the intervals may be dense in $[0,1]$ with the sum of their lengths being as small as you want. The complement of the union might be a "fat Cantor set", a certain type of closed, nowhere-dense, positive-measure set.